# Unable to use File read and write in c# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

For some reason, I'm unable to use File read and write in c# .net, error display like below

[image]

Where I do have the System.IO.Compression.FileSystem under my Reference

[image]

Does anyone know why and how could I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

That `File` is referring to the `Controller.File` method.

It's enough to fully qualify the type:

```
var sw = System.IO.File.CreateText(filePath);
```